# Ruby gem 'ruby oci8' returning Error: 'OCI.DLL: 126(The specified module could not be found. ) (LoadError)'

Tags: ruby, windows, oracle, activerecord, oci8

My platform:
 - Ruby 2.2.2p95 (2015-04-13 revision 50295) [x64-mingw32]
 - Windows 7 64bit

I have install Oracle Instant client i.e. the following:

- Oracle SDK
- Oracle SQLPLUS
- Oracle windows (I have the user variable path pointing to when Oracle windows install client oci.dll is installed - C:\Users\joebloggs\Documents\oracle\oracle_windows\instantclient_12_1)

And Ruby gems:

- 'ruby-oci8'
- 'activerecord'
- 'activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter'

When I run my code to try before I even call this method from activerecord ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(...) I encounter the following error:

```
OCI.DLL: 126(The specified module could not be found.  ) (LoadError)
C:/Users/joebloggs/Documents/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require'
C:/Users/joebloggs/Documents/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/2.2.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:54:in `require' 
C:/Users/joebloggs/Documents/Ruby22-x64/lib/ruby/gems/2.2.0/gems/ruby-oci8-2.2.1-x64-mingw32/lib/oci8.rb:72:in `<top (required)>'
```

I cannot see where the problem is. The PATH user variable is correctly set to where the oci.dll is in the Oracle Windows directory. Can anyone please help?

Many thanks, Irvz.

Comment: NOTE: The versions of the gems are:  1. activerecord (4.2.6),
2. activerecord-oracle_enhanced-adapter (1.6.7), 3. ruby-oci8 (2.2.1 x64-mingw32).

Comment: If OCI.DLL is surely in PATH, MSVCR100.DLL depended by the Oracle 12c OCI.DLL is not found in most cases. You need to install "Microsoft Visual C++ 2010 Redistributable Package" or copy MSVCR100.DLL to the directory where ruby.exe resides. See http://www.rubydoc.info/github/kubo/ruby-oci8/file/docs/install-instant-client.md#Windows

Answer (score 0):

I needed to add the '32bit' Folder to the $PATH, not the root folder of the Instantclient installation.